# ASP MVC running exe (process.start()) not working when published in IIS

Tags: c#, iis

I published a project on IIS where it has a module to run an executable file

```
    public static string shell_exec(string path,string args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.LoadUserProfile = true;
        p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\enroll.exe";
        p.FileName = path;
        p.Arguments = args;
        p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        var pc = Process.Start(p);
        WindowHelper.BringProcessToFront(pc);
        string output = pc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        pc.WaitForExit();
        return output;
    }
```

the executable file runs (i assume it, because its in the task manager) but not visible.
But the executable file is visible when your project runs in visual studio (IIS Express i believe).

I also edit the project's permission wherein all user has full control
[image]

I also edit the Application Pools setting
[image]
Did i setup a wrong configuration? or missing something?

Comment: So, you can see it in task manager, but it's"not visible"? Where do you expect it to be visible? You've published it to IIS. IIS runs in IIS-land, without a visible desktop, and with no interactions with any interactive users.

Comment: Im expecting it to be visible in the taskbar (client's pc or server itself)

Comment: Nope, your expectation is wrong.  It's running in a completely different context.